# Remove/100% Hide WinXP TaskBar

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, touchscreen

When AutoHide isn't enough, how can I code to gaurentee the taskbar can't be used/displayed while my application is running?

It's a full (touch)screen application (with no keyboard), that is being used in kiosk mode.

When the application exits it's ok to restore the taskbar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your application can be fullscreen and overlay the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Make your app a full screen window. Don't, however, search for the Taskbar and kill it in any way. It's bad behavior, punished with having yet another backward-compatibility hack in Windows API that Microsoft will have to support forever. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx) a post by Raymond Chen to teach you some manners. ;)
2. Make it Windows' shell instead of explorer.exe. That one's actually more appropriate, considering that your application is the only one that's supposed to be run on your 'kiosk'.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your application as shell, that way the taskbar doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Now I got a working solution in Delphi:
[App staying behind taskbar when starting in fullscreen!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942083/app-staying-behind-taskbar-when-starting-in-fullscreen/4943020#4943020)

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the tray window like this:

```
HWND trayWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);

if(trayWnd != NULL) {
    ShowWindow(trayWnd, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea, see linked article in the comment on the other answer.

Comment: The taskbar should hide caller's window in some kind of a retaliation. ;)

Comment: I know about the article, I even read Raymond's book. None of the described drawbacks apply here.

Comment: Still doesn't make it a good idea if there is a documented approach that works. And the drawback with the taskbar being another window class/title would still apply, by the way.

Comment: Documented approach that doesn't work, not the same way, the semantics are different. Never seen a bubble in the notification area of a kiosk computer informing you about new updates, drivers, hw? All hell really breaks loose when 'WM_SETTINGCHANGE' gets broadcasted, oh what a Z-fight. OP clearly stated 'How to hide/remove', not how to overlay while preaching MS's bible.