# C# Fullscreen, hiding the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, fullscreen

I have recently written an application for my daughter, which is a kid-free zone where she has all unnecessary key presses ignored (windows key, Esc etc) but the problem I am having is that when I use the following code:

```
targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
targetForm.TopMost = true;
```

I am able to HIDE the taskbar, but it is not truly overlayed. When I move the mouse to where the taskbar would be, and click, it pops up, also, using this code and running external applications withing my windows form, I am left with this windows form keeping itself on top.

If anyone could help me with a proper way to display my windows form as a true fullscreen application, and be able to run external applications from within the form and have them prioritize themselves on top, that would be greatly appreciated.

In case you missed it, I am using VS2010, C# and winforms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=win7+hide+taskbar **the search is your friend.**

Comment: What is the purpose of your application?

Comment: It's a child lockout app. So she can play her games and not click on anything else of mine. Creating a profile doesnt cut it, she can still access more than she needs.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove/100% Hide WinXP TaskBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962502/remove-100-hide-winxp-taskbar)

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to make a full-screen app is to just put something like `Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;` in your main form. Then when your app has focus it will cover the task bar.

You also probably want `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`

Comment: Thanks, will try this and let you know the outcome.

Comment: It doesn't help. The problem is the order of actions. Erez has the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

The order of the performed actions is incorrect.
You should first hide the border (FormBorderStyle=None), and then set the window state to maximized. You even don't have to set TopMost to true.

Comment: This works! Why is this not marked as the right answer?!