# PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height is not the full screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form. I'm setting it's size using the following code. My desired behaviour is to have it take the full width and half the height of the primary display.

```
this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);
```

The problem is there is a space on the right form (it's not taking up the full screen). Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

Thanks

Comment: Aero enabled?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8839388/17034

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

Comment: @Jleru0HeP thanks for your response. I tried that and there is still a small gap on the side. It looks to be with width of the scroll bar.

Comment: Maybe your form then resizes a little again?

Comment: Adding + ~30 pixels to the Width will fill it so it seems the working area or bounds is considered to be slightly inside the desktop bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to make it fullscreen:

```cs
// maximize the form
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

or

```cs
// hide the border
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

You can try them together but have to [notice the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054457/c-sharp-fullscreen-hiding-the-taskbar?answertab=active#tab-top), hide the border first, then set the window state to maximized.