# WinForm enter fullscreen mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `WinForm` application and i want to enter fullscreen mode and remove all bars and the task bar.
i done it with this:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TopMost = true;
```

The top bar is really hidden but the Windows `TaskBar` is still visible.
Any idea what can be the trouble?

Comment: [The Same Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054457/c-sharp-fullscreen-hiding-the-taskbar)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16618/How-To-Make-a-Windows-Form-App-Truly-Full-Screen-a

Comment: Just swap the top two lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run with full screen you can use this method..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

To Hide `TaskBar` Just add this class into your project .it works as you expected.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, int childAfter, string className, int windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    protected static int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        }
    }

    protected static int HandleOfStartButton
    {
        get
        {
            int handleOfDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
            int handleOfStartButton = FindWindowEx(handleOfDesktop, 0, "button", 0);
            return handleOfStartButton;
        }
    }

    private Taskbar()
    {
        // hide ctor
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_SHOW);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
Taskbar.Hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Reorder lines to maximize the form after will will be marked with FormBorderStyle.None and TopMost

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: It's still won't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your statements, try:

```
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```